# FastApi runs with DockerFile doesn't run with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I have this simple project structure:
[image: project structure]

I use FastApi as backend and React as frontend.

When I run FastApi DockerFile it works just fine:

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app .

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

[image: Checked using curl]

But the moment I use docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./FastAPI
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build: ./React/react-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime
> create failed: runc create failed: unable to start c ontainer process:
> exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
> `docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1

Comment: try without command in docker-compose. Use CMD in dockerfile

Comment: @Mate, done. Still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

1st delete your "backend" local image

```
docker rmi -f {imageid}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./FastAPI
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

requirements.txt

```
fastapi==0.95.*
uvicorn[standard]==0.21.*
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: After 6 hours with this I understood I only needed to rebuilt this backend image...

Comment: oohhh, typical!