# "sudo docker-compuse up" leaves me frozen/stuck with booting workers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, deployment, gunicorn

I'm trying to get my docker-compose up but it gets stuck with the workers booting
If I try to go to the local host port it just shows "The site can't be reached" page as well

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/python:3.10

WORKDIR /

# --- [Install python and pip] ---
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip git
COPY . /

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

# --- ADDED TIMEOUT FOR FIX ---
ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--workers=3 --bind=0.0.0.0:8080 --timeout=1000"

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "gunicorn", "main:app" ]
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
        web:
                image: runtime_t_v1
                build: .
                ports:
                        - "8032:8080"
                volumes:
                        - ./volumes:/volumes
                        - ./instance:/instance
                restart: unless-stopped
```

This is the error:

```
(base) Theo@Theo runtime_flask % sudo docker-compose up
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container runtime_flask-web-1  Created                                                                                       0.0s
Attaching to runtime_flask-web-1
runtime_flask-web-1  | [2023-04-07 20:23:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
runtime_flask-web-1  | [2023-04-07 20:23:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
runtime_flask-web-1  | [2023-04-07 20:23:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
runtime_flask-web-1  | [2023-04-07 20:23:34 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
runtime_flask-web-1  | [2023-04-07 20:23:34 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
runtime_flask-web-1  | [2023-04-07 20:23:34 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
```

When I looked up the problem, people either put a timeout on gunicorn or increased their memory cap on Docker. I tried both but neither work. You can also see the timeout I added to gunicorn within my docker-compose file. I've tried everything I've seen online with the same problem but nothing has worked but maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844128/fastapi-runs-with-dockerfile-doesnt-run-with-docker-compose/75844335#75844335

Comment: Still no unfortunately, I deleted the image and built it again but same error

Comment: How do you run your docker compose file?  Try using " up -d "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my last comment:

1. Avoid run docker / docker-compose as root.
   You could add your user to group = docker.
2. If you run `docker compose up -d` (detach) the containers run in the background. Otherwise, you stop them when close or cancel the running command.